# Firepath Tab not appearing when we click F12(FireBug)

Tags: selenium, firefox

I have installed 0.9.7.1.1 version of Firepath and 2.0.18 of Firebug.

I am unable to see the Firepath tab in the FireBug window.

Comment: which version of Firefox you are using ?

Comment: i Use 51.0.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Open about:config
Set **false** to following:

- browser.tabs.remote.autostart
- browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1
- browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2